# API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, fabric.io

Using Android Studio 3.3 Canary 11 with the gradle plugin version `3.3.0-alpha11`. It throws the following error when trying to sync gradle

```
WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been 
replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration- 
avoidance
Affected Modules: app
```

Clicking on the error leads me to this line in the gradle file

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
            }
        }
```

What exactly do I need to change here?

project `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha11'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Define versions in a single place
ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 21
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'

    // App dependencies
    supportLibraryVersion = '27.1.1'
    appCompactLibraryVersion = '27.1.1'
    playServicesVersion = '15.0.1'
    firebaseVersionCore = '16.0.1'
    firebaseVersionPerf = '16.0.0'
    firebaseVersionMessaging = '17.1.0'

    //lottie
    lottieVersion = '2.5.0'
}
```

app build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            mavenCentral()

        }

        dependencies {
            // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
            // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

            // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
            // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:'
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {

    realm {
        syncEnabled = false
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode mVersionCode
        versionName mVersionName
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
            }
        }

        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }

        }
        debug {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            debuggable true
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'debug-proguard-rules.pro'

            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            crunchPngs false

        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
}

configurations {
    implementation.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.appCompactLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"


    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'

    implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.5'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
    // Wifi hotspot library
    implementation 'cc.mvdan.accesspoint:library:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    api "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$rootProject.lottieVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'

    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'

    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.2.0'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.firebaseVersionCore"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$rootProject.firebaseVersionPerf"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$rootProject.firebaseVersionMessaging"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$rootProject.firebaseVersionCore"


    api('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    api('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    api project(path: ':libraryBTHelper')
    api project(':bkk_rush')

    debugApi 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.3'
    api "org.jdeferred:jdeferred-android-aar:1.2.6"
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have skipped out a few constants and other sensitive information in the app/build.gradle file.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle(app)?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS added the project build.gradle file

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116148147

Comment: @alashow this is related to different issue, message there is "API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete.."

Comment: Issue exists with the stable version as well

Comment: Also exists with updating fabric gradle plugin to the latest version(1.27.0)

Comment: @JudeFernandes do you know there is a difference between warning and error?

Comment: You can now fix it with `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'`

Comment: Issue has been fixed in latest release. Check the comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193824/3806413

Comment: I'm still getting this warning with `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'` and `implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'`

Comment: Fabric is deprecated at March 31, 2020 and it's development been moved completely to Firebase Crashlytics

Answer (score 293, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in their latest release `'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.30.0'`

Please update your both gradle fabric tools with **1.30.0**

```
buildscript {
  // ... repositories, etc. ...

   dependencies {
       // ...other dependencies ...
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.30.0'
   }
}
```

For more details https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/198#issuecomment-473435453

Comment: Make sure to change it in the build.gradle in both the project level and app.

Comment: Version 1.28.0 fixed my problem, current version is 1.29.0  https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin

Comment: Here is the ChangeLog: https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#march-15-2019

Comment: I'm still getting this warning with `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'` and `implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'`. It's either broken again or not fixed for all cases.

Comment: Where did you get this fabric tools gradle version? I can only find 1.25.4
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.fabric.tools/gradle

Comment: Fabric is deprecated at March 31, 2020 and it's development been moved completely to Firebase Crashlytics

Answer (score 249):

**EDIT**

This issue has been fixed in [Fabric 1.28.0](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#march-15-2019). In your `build.gradle` of the project level, add the following line:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
```

---

**Previous Answer**

It happens after I updated Android Studio to 3.3.0. `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` is the cause. I have sent a bug report to Firebase team about this issue.

You have 3 options:

- Wait until the next version of Fabric plugin is released. Check the latest version [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin).
- Downgrade to [Android Studio 3.2.1](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/3.2.1.0/android-studio-ide-181.5056338-windows.exe).
- Comment out `io.fabric` plugin.

In `build.gradle` of your app's module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// apply plugin: 'io.fabric' <== this plugin causes the error
```

However, you can still build and run your projects even though this error appears. Just ignore it.

Comment: yes same error here. Cannot build project. revert back to 3.2

Comment: Would it be possible for you to link to the bug report or issue you opened with Firebase? I'd love to upvote it.

Comment: Sorry @yuval, I cannot put the link. Firebase does not provide a public bug tracking like Google Issue Tracker. They do it via email only.

Comment: app crashes at runtime after doing this.

Comment: I have to use the `io.fabric` plugin then how can i remove this warning without changing this?

Comment: And Also disable the dependency of Crashlytics.

Comment: This is the cause, not a viable solution

Comment: I cannot use Crashlytics now.

Comment: They are saying that you can use it until end of the 2019 year. For now I'm using, we will see what happens )

Comment: @DarshanMiskin this is normal, either remove completely crashlytics or keep the warning for now. If your app is not building at all you can check comments below for solution

Comment: This definitely seems to be the cause, wouldn't migrating to Firebase crashlytics solve this, since Fabric is integrating it's features in to Firebase, i'm following this guide: https://proandroiddev.com/migrating-crashlytics-to-the-firebase-console-5e05b6ff8c12

Comment: Why downgrading? No sense! It's just a warning, it's not removed yet and it can build your project (the whole 2019 year...). I believe they will fix it during this year

Comment: I agree for just a warning downgrading seems too extreme. If its a platform change the (google) will most probably make it explicit for instance that we should move from fabric to firebase crashlystics type-configuration

Comment: For now the best thing to do is to live with the warning. Maybe they'll fix it in the near future

Comment: `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1` is still having this issue.

Comment: I got .this error after removing this.
The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration

Comment: https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin and https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install have the latest versions.

Answer (score 61):

In application `build.gradle`, downgrade to this stable version of gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

It happens after I updated Android Studio to 3.3, a temp solution until they fix it.

---

**Edit:**
You don't need to downgrade your Android Studio

Comment: Then you also have to downgrade to Android Studio 3.2.1. Thanks anyway

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading Android Studio (AS) to version 3.3. I got Gradle sync to work again by downgrading Gradle to version 4.6 and Android Gradle Plugin to version 3.2.1, which was the versions I was using prior to the AS update. Look up the table [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) if you are doubt how to modify the versions for gradle and the plugin.

Comment: It worked without downgrading anything thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Since my answer was converted into the comment you see above let me add that I couldn't get the proposed solution of this answer to work by only changing the version of the gradle plugin to 3.2.1. I had to also downgrade gradle to 4.6, otherwise gradle sync would still complain.

Comment: you don't need to downgrade your android studio @RubénViguera

Comment: You don't need to downgrade anything other than gradle version as mentioned in the answer. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

**UPDATE**
As of today you can use `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'` to fix this issue !

If commenting out `Crashlytics`'s plugin `io.fabric` on the app gradle file worked for you temporarily

```
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Then upgrading your fabric gradle dependencies on the Project gradle file will permanently solve the issue:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
```

NB: this doesn’t remove the warnings but let you use Crashlytics with AS3.3+

Comment: @RJB  Are you using Crashlytics? If you remove it from your project it works ? If yes then this should fix the issue. However you might still get warnings, but the project will compila and you can generate your apk safely

Comment: Yes. I mean that I am still getting the warning.

Comment: the op and others (including me) had this issue and were unable to compile the project with `crashlytics` enabled. So to keep Crashlytics and still push to prod you can use the above mentioned update even though it still trigger "warnings".

Answer (score 14):

Not sure what the actual issue is but commenting out the crashlytics related dependencies from the project solved issue.

Answer (score 12):

It's confirmed as bug for Crashlytics and they are working on it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116408637

Quoted from Google assignee:

> je...@google.com    #23 Jan 23, 2019 01:40AM
>   Hi  all,
>
> Thank you for your patience.
>
> It looks like the bug in all cases is coming from crashlytics and I've
>   filed a bug with them.
>
> I will keep you updated on the status.

For me, my debug app is working fine on my device just by running and ignoring the warning without commenting Crashlytics or Fabric. I have not try for production.

**Update:**

Google Issue Tracker had mark this issues as Won't Fix (Infeasible) because all the issues was from Crashlytics, and let fixes done by Crashlytics team (despite they are same Googler...).

They suggest to follow this link for Crashlytics updates:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/198

Note: I'm still using Android Studio 3.3 with io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.0 without commenting any of Craslytics and it's works fine on my debug app.

**Update:**

I can confirm now that it works fine on my production/release version app. How do I know it works? Because it had sent me back a crash reports -_-'

Anyway, just ignore the warning, they should fix it eventually.

Aww, just read that it had fixed with fabric 1.28.0 :)

Answer (score 9):

Latest news from 01/24/2019

[image]

Info here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116408637

We will need to wait untill Crashlytics came up with a solution, here is GitHub issue opened

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/198

The only way I'm using as right now to not comment **io.fabric** plugin is downgrading my gradle and upgrading my fabric classpath (this is working on my production app)

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: How about we just add `-dontwarn com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics` in `proguard-rules.pro`

Comment: If you remove the warning by doing that the problem is still there and you will need to eventually get back to the problem again

Comment: Right! It is a temp solution to get build compiled, but it is much better than downgrading everything.

Comment: Yes, downgrading it will cause to work, if you dismiss the warning you can keep the updated version but it won't work

Comment: @Mustansir, I think it's a gradle-related problem and has nothing to do with Proguard.

Answer (score 5):

As it was said, the problem is with Fabric/Crashlytics.

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

It's a bug on Crashlytics/Firebase side, please check the following link and see the bug' status : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/198

Answer (score 4):

the issue-tracker might refer to "lazy task configuration" -

that's at least what [task configuration avoidance](https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance) suggests.

but one possibly can prevent the access to this obsolete method of `BaseVariantImpl`, when `variant.outputs.all` won't access that method (internally) - or when checks can prevent the access; or when accessing the variant by it's name; or somehow disable the external native build tasks for the variant. also see the [single-variant project sync](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#gradle_version) option, which rather seems related.

or wait for [build-tools](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google) `3.3.0-alpha12` or `3.3.0-beta1` ...this is not even a `release candidate`, therefore investing to much time might be pointless - except using it to file another bug-report.

the new quick feedback [image: quick feedback] button still looks the most promising.

Comment: Yes, i agree, this type of error was not present in the previous build tools. The next RC may fix it

Comment: it was not fixed in the release

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-3-0 ...add `android.debug.obsoleteApi=true` to see where it comes from. there were a few methods renamed, with `Provider` appended to their name.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, where to put this in to make AS checking obsolete api? I mean android.debug.obsoleteApi=true

Comment: @SergeyNarozhnyy in project gradle.properties

Comment: @SergeyNarozhnyy the `3.3.0` release broken a few things, since the variant API had changed. can link one recent discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206898/variantoutput-getpackageapplication-is-obsolete (added a summary as an answer there).

Answer (score 4):

For me, I followed these steps:
1. upgrade the Gradle dependency on project level build.gradle.

```
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
```

2. add this plugin dependency below   **apply plugin: 'com.android.application'** 
   in the app level build.gradle.

   ```
       apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
   ```
3. Sync the project with gradle files.

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to the update of your Android Studio from Android Studio 3.2.0 to Android Studio 3.3.0. Update Your Gradle Dependencies (Project)of IO.Fabric. Like:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
```

and also update your Kotlin version to

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20"
```

This will resolve this issues.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me.

Comment: @Sean If you are using Kotlin and io febric.then It works otherwise for working downgrade your classpath version.It will works...

Comment: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration

Answer (score 1):

this has been fixed in the latest release of the Fabric gradle plugin, 1.28.0, which went live today.
Have this in your top-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
// ... repositories, etc. ...

dependencies {
    // ...other dependencies ...
    **classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'**
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Build log prints how to debug this, particularly you need to run build with `-Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true`, that'll print stack-trace of call to deprecated API and you'll be able to figure which plugin/code calls it.

**If it ends up being your code** — use new Provider API ([read Lazy Task Configuration doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html))

**If it comes from other plugin** — report to them with stack-trace and warning message and maybe submit a patch. As in this case its related to `io.fabric` issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I opened the project, I pressed the `Run migrations` button appeared on the right bottom corner from `Android Studio`. A migration was performed and the problem was solve without commenting out the `Crashlytics` dependency.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing source compatibility in module `build.gradle` file to Java 8 fixes the issue

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}
```

Be sure to rebuild the project after adding those lines

Comment: In top level `build.gradle` or module level (/app) ?

Comment: module level(app)

Answer (score 0):

this will fix the error :
On the taskbar click Tools->Kotlin->Configure Kotlin in Project

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to use **`io.fabric`** plugin, and the solution was, to update to the latest fabric tools gradle version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to keep the Fabric plugin applied, the temporary solution is to go back to the previous version of the gradle at the project level.

Change the classpath version to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with latest `gradle` (in my case `3.3.2`) version and `Fabric.io` plugin.
It is now solved by the new version
Users should have this in their top-level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
   // ... repositories, etc. ...

    dependencies {
        // ...other dependencies ...
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix is update the root build gradle files to latest. And this answer hold true now. in fureture again new change will be implementing by gradle and android SDK. At times answer will vary in due course of time.

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.30.0'
}
```

Answer (score -7):

first of all this is not an **error**

it's **warning**

and
its show up when update gradle to 3.3.0
Often occur because io.fabric so wait until the update fabric
current version where warning is still show up is 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'