# Android studio3.3 variantOutput.getProcessResources() is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()

Tags: android, gradle

What is bellow warning:

```
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470044/warning-api-variant-getjavacompile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with)

Answer (score 15):

It's the bug in https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip .

You need to roll back to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties

And

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' //roll back to this version
```

I have deal with this bug for 4 hours. I gave up so I rolled back to last version. It's perfect now. So let's wait for the newer version. Don't upgrade, yet!

Comment: Also worked for me, but i do not how to fix it with a real solution, any news on this issue?

Comment: I have tried the upgrade last week. My app is working fine with butter knife 9, not 10[not working]. It's just a warning.

Answer (score 3):

run a gradle task with this flag `-Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true`
and it will let you know where the obsolete feature is being used.

After identifying where the issue is, you can try updating as the message suggests

ex. `.gradlew app:assembleDebug -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true`

Comment: that should be the correct answer. I've found an obsolete library which was not being shown

Answer (score 0):

I do not need to change the default of " classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' ". This is the default that I copy from firebase, it really has been updated but we do not need to update it.