# User Login Issue . Login Screen only being processed . User can't Login

Tags: android, android-studio

Since I updated my android studio to the latest version before that my application was working fine but now I cannot Sign in my application. 
after giving username and password login screen only being processed but not logging in.

[image: See Image]

What could be the problem, please help?

This is the medthod for uploading data .

```
 public void uploadGroupData() {
    CommonMethod.writeToFile(new Gson().toJson(groupSyncUpData));

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

    params.put("group_data", new Gson().toJson(groupSyncUpData));

    Log.e("ParamsJason : ", "" + params);

    PhpConnectivity.getClient().post(CommonConst.GROUP_TEST_URL, params, 
                                 new 
            AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            progressDialog.setTitle("Group Sync Up");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Group  Data Uploading...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            String response = new String(responseBody);
            if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(RESPONSE_SUCCESS)) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                CommonMethod.alert(SyncUpActivity.this
                        , "Group Sync Up:", "Success");
                dbHandler.updateGroupSync(groupSyncUpData.getGroup().getGroupId(), 1);
                recAdapter.getItemList().remove(groupSyncUpData.getGroup());
                recAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                groupSyncUpData = null;
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + response);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                CommonMethod.alert(SyncUpActivity.this
                        , "Group Sync Up Failure:", "Response: " + response);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            if (responseBody == null) {
                CommonMethod.alert(SyncUpActivity.this
                        , "Connectivity Error:", "Try Again!");
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                return;
            }
            String response = new String(responseBody);
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + response);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            CommonMethod.alert(SyncUpActivity.this
                    , "Group Sync Up Failure:", "Response: " + response);

        }
    });
}
```

method for logging in inside login activity

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    final Login login = new Login();
    if (view == loginBtn) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("logging in...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        username = UsernameEdt.getText().toString();
        password = PasswordEdt.getText().toString();
        Log.e(TAG, "onClick: --" + username + "---" + password);

        if (CommonMethod.isNetworkAvailable2(this)) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(45000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(45000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(45000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
            AndroidNetworking.post(CommonConst.LOGIN_URL_TEST)
                    .addBodyParameter("Username", username)
                    .addBodyParameter("Password", password)
                    .setTag("login")
                    .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                    .setOkHttpClient(okHttpClient) // passing a custom 
                    okHttpClient
                    .build()
                    .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new 
                    JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                   String EmployeeId = jsonObject.getString("EmployeeId");
                   String Firstname = jsonObject.getString("FirstName");
                   String Lastname = jsonObject.getString("LastName");
                   String Cnic = jsonObject.getString("NICNumber");
                   String Username = jsonObject.getString("UserName");
                   String Password = jsonObject.getString("Password");
                   String empTypeId = 
                     jsonObject.getString("EmployeeTypeId");
                                String empTypeName = jsonObject.getString("EmployeeTypeName");

                                Log.e("typeId : ", empTypeId);
                                Log.e("typeName : ", empTypeName);


                                String md5Pass = MD5.encrypt(password);
                                login.setEmployee_Id(EmployeeId);
                                login.setEmployee_F_Name(Firstname);
                                login.setEmployee_L_Name(Lastname);
                                login.setEmployee_NIC(Cnic);
                                login.setEmployee_Username(Username);
                                login.setEmployee_Password(md5Pass);
                                login.setEmployeeTypeId(empTypeId);
                                login.setEmployeeTypeName(empTypeName);

                            int loginId = Integer.parseInt(EmployeeId);

                         int checking = dbHandler.checkingLogin(EmployeeId);
                                if (checking == 1) {
                                   // showRepaymentFPDialog2(EmployeeId);
                                    preferences.setIsLoggedIn(true);
                                    preferences.setFirstName(username);
                                    preferences.setEmployeeId(loginId);
                                    preferences.setEmployeeTypeName(empTypeName);

                                    Intent goAct = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(goAct);
                                    finish();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    long res = dbHandler.insertLoginData(login);
                                                                            if (res != -1) {
                                        preferences.setIsLoggedIn(true);
                                        preferences.setFirstName(username);
                                        preferences.setEmployeeId(loginId);
                                        preferences.setEmployeeTypeName(empTypeName);

                                        Intent goAct = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(goAct);
                                        finish();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                                    } else {
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(ANError error) {
                            UsernameEdt.setError("Invalid");
                            PasswordEdt.setError("Invalid");
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Username or Password" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });

        } else {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            String EncryptedPass = password;
            String md5Pass = MD5.encrypt(EncryptedPass);
            int logged = dbHandler.LoginInFromDB(username,md5Pass);

            Log.e(TAG, "onClick0: "+logged +":"+md5Pass+":"+EmpId);
            if(logged ==1){
                preferences.setFirstName(username);
                preferences.setEmployeeId(preferences.getEmployeeId());
                EmpId = String.valueOf(preferences.getEmployeeId());

                preferences.setIsLoggedIn(true);

                Intent goAct = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(goAct);
                finish();
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }else {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                UsernameEdt.setError("Invalid");
                PasswordEdt.setError("Invalid");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting these Warning after updating android studio .

[image]

can anybody help with that?

here is Gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}}
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shery.safco"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.094"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        resValue("string", "PORT_NUMBER", "8083")
    }
  }}
 dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
   layout:1.0.2'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
   androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.droidninja:filepicker:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:jackson-android-networking:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation files('libs/FDxSDKProAndroid.jar')
//    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation files('libs/MD5Simply.jar')
```

}

Comment: check your logs for problem

Comment: Check something got missed in back end.Check response

Comment: provide your code please. people cannot guess.

Comment: @VivekMishra there is no error in logcat .

Comment: @ramyabr i haven't changed my code just updated the android studio .

Comment: @ZaidMirza There is no error in code , i don't see any error in logcat . what should i do now . ?

Comment: We cant guess without looking into code.

Comment: It may something got changed from back end.Check the response from the server.

Comment: You need to share your code

Comment: @ZaidMirza please check now ,

Comment: @Sniffer shared . check now

Comment: @Sniffer Please have a look at code now .

Comment: @ZaidMirza Please have a look at code now

Comment: Your code looks okay... try to invalidate cache/restart in Android Studio

Comment: @Sniffer okay , please i need up-vote if you think my question is valid otherwise will be banned from asking more questions .

Comment: Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive well reputation on SO

Comment: @Sniffer done validate cache/restart . Still same problem .

Comment: @Sniffer i updated my question please have a look at android studio warnings

Comment: @ZaidMirza i updated my question please have a look at android studio warnings

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470224/5978440)

Answer (score -1):

In New Android Studio version you need to check security. And for that please refer this link [Security-config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config). And this type of issue occur in android 8 and 9.

Also You need to use secure URL like https://. if you are using http:// then this type of issue occur.

replace below code in related match

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Comment: then check the above link Security-Config.

Comment: i updated my android studio now getting warnings , please have look at my question and see android studio SS @ankur

Comment: okay for this currently no solution available So for that the temporary solution you can downgrade your gradle version in class-path. i think you are using 3.3.0. then downgrade this version to 3.2.1. It may help you for temporary.

Comment: It's probably coming from the Crashlytics plugin. We need to wait for an update from the Fabric (now Google) people.

In the meantime it's just a warning - albeit a very distracting and annoying one - so you can (try to) ignore it.

Comment: yes i am using 3.3 . and how can i downgrade? 

updated my Question plese check my gradle file . @ankur

Comment: i did change my gradle with the code u provided . Still getting the same warnings . @ankur

Comment: Still same issue .

Comment: If you are not using the NDK then remove this code from gradle.                                ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }

Comment: still not working , installed previous version of android studio but still got same issue .

Comment: There's a default trust anchor in Android that's used if you don't set one up explicitly.  So this wiill not be his problem.