# How to access log error details when using 'android.debug.obsoleteApi=true' in gradle.properties file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compilation, build.gradle

I am new to contributing to open source projects. I am working on a project in Android Studio. I updated the gradle tools version to 3.3.0. I found a warning (not an error) that says "API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'." However, variant.getJavaCompile() is not explicitly stated in the problem gradle file. I have to find what is calling the method.

I researched the issue and found this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?utm_source=android-studio#new_features
It explains how the new features of the update effect the gradle.

I also came across this helpful post: [WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470044/warning-api-variant-getjavacompile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with/54213973#54213973)
@Ewoks says that we can find it by adding 'android.debug.obsoleteApi=true' to gradle.properties file which will log the error.

I added the snippet to my properties.gradle file then I looked at the logcat in Android Studio. When I run the project, the logcat shows the steps the app is taking to run on my phone, but it doesn't say anything about an obsolete API.

Where do I look to find the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by accident. I synced the project again. This time, the warning showed me where to find the obsolete call.