# variant.getAssemble() is obsolete and has been replaced with variant.getAssembleProvider()

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I didn't call variant.getAssemble() from my project but still showing these messages. When I try to run the project I get this error "Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors in Android Studio
"

```
'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
```

Gradle.build file is here, I don't use variant.getAssemble() here. If the system is calling this then where can I find it to solve the issue. I have multiple modules.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'

dependencies {

implementation project(':A')
implementation project(':B')
implementation project(':C')
implementation project(':D')
//implementation project(':E')
implementation project(':F')
implementation project(':G')

implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$project.supportVersion"

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$project.firebaseCore"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$project.firebaseAds"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$project.firebaseAuth"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$project.firebaseMessaging"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$project.firebaseCrash"

implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$project.gsonVersion"
implementation "com.google.guava:guava:$project.guavaVersion"
implementation "org.jsoup:jsoup:$project.jsoupVersion"
implementation "ch.acra:acra:$project.acraVersion"
implementation "com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:$project.volleyVersion"
// optional

debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:$project.leackcanaryVersion"
releaseImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$project.leackcanaryVersion"
testImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$project.leackcanaryVersion"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$project.RetrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$project.RetrofitGsonVersion"
}

android {

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XXX.XXXX"
    multiDexEnabled = true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def relativeRootDir = output.packageApplication.outputDirectory.toPath().relativize(rootDir.toPath()).toFile()
        output.outputFileName = new File( "$relativeRootDir" + File.separator+"libs", project.name+"-"+project.versionName+".apk")
    }
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Any similarity with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470044/warning-api-variant-getjavacompile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with

Comment: No, thanks for the response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variantOutput.getPackageApplication() is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206898/variantoutput-getpackageapplication-is-obsolete)

Comment: When I hide this line "apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'" get this error "WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019."  And If I don't hide this line I get this error "WARNING: API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019." And If I run the project I find this error "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs". Please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You can safely ignore it. Some plugins like Fabric cause those warnings, as it's devs have to adapt to new Android Studio/Gradle releases. Just make sure to use latest versions of your dependencies.

Comment: no Fabrics like library is added, all versions are up to date

Comment: ```apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'``` 

Probably this one is the culprit, you can try to comment it out. But then your crash analytics will not work, so simply ignore the warning. Your app will still work fine.

Comment: Now I get this Error message : "API 'variantOutput.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.
"

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` Well, only this one can cause this, but your build will _probably_ break without it

Comment: Check what is the error in AndroidManifest.xml.
Open AndroidManifest.xml file and select 'Merged Manifests' tab below the file window.