# Gradle regression when looking for google-services.json?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I updated to the last Android Studio, which led me to update gradle as well.
While I had had to change the location of the google-services.json file in the past to adapt for changes in gradle, now it seems that gradle is looking for this file in the old location

```
./MyProject/app/google-services.json
```

The problem is that this location does not make sense anymore since I have multiple flavor with different google-services.json files.
Now, I placed them in

```
./MyProject/app/src/MyFlavor/release/google-services.json
./MyProject/app/src/MyFlavor/debug/google-services.json
```

How can I deal with this new "regression"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 
I found it was a real regression, and I will need to post a bug report to Google.

I have solved this problem by reading this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823777/2231299

So basically, it comes from

```
'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

and the temporary solution is to go back to

```
'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```