# API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'

Tags: android, flutter, build, google-play

I have build an app in Flutter. It worked fine on the simulations and real devices as well as on the Iphone X and a android phone.

The upload to Apples appstore went fine, but I dont get it build for the the Google play store.

Every time I got several failures and now I am out of cards. I just don't understand what the code is saying and what I have to do.

(As a beginner I was also surprised about the difficult way and lot of steps you had to do to make even a file you can upload. I find it even more difficult then programming. I hope they will made this easier, such as as it is running on a simulator, make this the build file.)

Run it in Android. Followed the steps on the fluttersite.

```
* Error running Gradle:
  abnormally:
  Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :app
WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with
'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command
line to display more information.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with
'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-   avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command
line to display more information.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with
'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-       avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the
command line to display more information.
     *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of shared_preferences will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't
compatible with AndroidX.
     See (had to remove this url) for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
     This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be
     unrelated.
     *********************************************************

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Comment: This link will help you: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470044/warning-api-variant-getjavacompile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with>

Comment: I have seen this. Same issue, lots of solutions which one do I use and how? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those failures I had was because I did things wrong when I followed the steps in the Flutter doc.

Finally I found a YouTube video of MTECHVIRAL, and just by doing what he did, I got a apk file which I could upload. For other flutterfriends who got the same error, try this first. Save you a lot of time and frustrations:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGvPNG-f1-o

Watch out: in the sentence with the key he makes a typo: 1000 which has to be 10000. So copy and past the sentence of the flutter instruction page.