# Warning in variant.getJavaCompiler() , variant.getJavaCompileProvider(), variantOutput.getPackageLibrary(), variant.getPackageLibraryProvider()

Tags: android, androidx

I am regularly getting Warning message:

API `variant.getJavaCompiler()` is obsolete and has been replaced with `variant.getJavaCompileProvider()`.

API `variantOutput.getPackageLibrary()` is obsolete and has been replaced with `variant.getPackageLibraryProvider()`.

Comment: check this like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470044/warning-api-variant-getjavacompile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470044/warning-api-variant-getjavacompile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with)