# How do I find alternate method on deprecated Gradle methods?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle task on my app-level build.gradle file. Gradle warning tells me that this method is deprecated `variant.getJavaCompiler()`. But I can't find any documentation for `variant.getJavaCompileProvider()` array method.

`API 'variant.getJavaCompiler()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'. It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin. For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.`

And the task is:

```
afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.javaCompiler.dependsOn externalSources, buildCoreVersion
    }
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().toLowerCase()
    if (tskReqStr.contains("huawei")) {
        apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your classpath dependency in project level Gradle:

```
buildscript {
// ... repositories, etc. ...

dependencies {
    // ...other dependencies ...
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.30.0'
}}
```

By the way before asking for help try to find it on google this question is already answered here:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55703788/13694485