# AGP 3.3 and Gradle 5.0 warning for variants that are obsolete and will be removed at the end of 2019

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've been using AS 3.3-rc1 with AGP 3.3-rc1 and updated to Gradle 5.0

Since then I've got this warnings.

Does anyone know how can I get rid of them?

Cannot figure out anything from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/?utm_source=android-studio#lazy_task_config) and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:old_vs_new_configuration_api_overview).

Could it be only because they are RC versions or what?

```
WARNING: API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getAssemble(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessManifest()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessManifestProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessManifest(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
WARNING: API 'variant.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getPackageApplication(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
```

**UPDATE:**

With my old friend *Divide et Impera* approach I found the culprit and is Fabric Gradle Plugin

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Looking forward for their github repo to see if there's already an issue or not.

Anyway I guess that in the long run these warnings will go away as soon as fabric will make their plugin compliant with the new API.

**UPDATE 2**

Fabric GitHub issue related with that:

- *This is the **general** one:* https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/230
- *This is the more indexed one:*  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/198 indexed by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412023/api-variant-getexternalnativebuildtasks-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-wi).

All you have to do is nothing, just w8 for next Fabric Plugin release.

Comment: I guess this question is related with that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412023/api-variant-getexternalnativebuildtasks-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-wi I leave here also my question for a better indexing of the issue. (unluckily for me I've found it only after all my investigation... ^^)

Comment: yes! io.fabric is to blame, I confirm!

Answer (score 2):

Add below line to **`project/gradle/wrapper/Gradle-wrapper.properties`** .

> **android.debug.obsoleteApi=true**

[image: visit this link..]

Comment: Thanks, As you can read in my updated question I've already found out which plugin causes this warnings. Btw, that's (and should have been) a nice hint.

Comment: Thanks, Worked for me.

Comment: fix: actually that needs to be added in gradle-wrapper.properties not in Gradle.properties .. Cheers

Comment: `gradle-wrapper.properties` is related to gradle wrapper it has nothing to do with this warning.