# WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Unable to resolve this warning. How can I resolve this?

```
 variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 
 variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412023/api-variant-getexternalnativebuildtasks-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-wi)

Comment: Here is the fix provided. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193824/3806413

Answer (score 18):

Just update Fabric gradle plugin to 1.28.0

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Add this `android.debug.obsoleteApi=true` to the `gradle.properties` file. And make gradle clean, sync and then build an APK. Worked for me. I have Android Studio 3.3 and Gradle version 4.10.1.

For more information check this link out: [Android Gradle plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?utm_source=android-studio#3-2-0.).

I agree with other contributors: Fabric causes this error.

**UPDATE**

Check [Valdislav Panchenko's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6108739/vladyslav-panchenko) answer:

Now you can just update your Fabric plugin to 1.28.0 as follows:

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
}
```

Comment: You can also use this flag with the command `./gradlew assembleDebug -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true`

Answer (score 7):

Most likely it's caused by Fabric's plugin needed for Crashlytics.

Commenting out `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` resolves the issue. So the only option is to wait until Google devs will fix Fabric's plugin.

Answer (score 4):

It's caused by one of the Gradle plugins used in your project.
Check build.gradle file and try to remove `apply plugin: xxx` one by one to understand exactly which plugin is causing the warning.
In our project it was `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` after Google update Android Studio to 3.3 yesterday.

Comment: I removed fabric plugin from build.gradle and the warning has finally gone.Thanks you for the support.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me but I needed to continue with the Fabric plugin.

For those who need to keep the Fabric plugin applied, the temporary solution is to go back to the previous version of the gradle at the project level.

Change the classpath version to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing this problem eventhough they dont use fabric, forget about Vitaly Zeyenko's updated answer above and simply go to the gradle folder of your project and open the gradle.properties file and add this line -->>>  **android.debug.obsoleteApi=true**  to it...

After that, Clean and rebuild project... This is a better solution than on the command line because a lot of people already have the JDK environment set to wrong locations on their computer and might face more problems solving this issue through the command line

[image: gradle-wrapper.properties in gradle->wrapper]