# How to use new method variant.getGenerateBuildConfigProvider() from Android Gradle plugin's Variant API?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading Android Gradle plugin to version 3.3.0 in one of my projects, I got several new warnings during syncing the project. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to tackle one of them. The warning is:

> WARNING: API 'variant.getGenerateBuildConfig()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getGenerateBuildConfigProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getGenerateBuildConfig(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.

The code line, which causes the warning is:
`variant.generateBuildConfig.appPackageName` in one of my gradle files.

My question is, how should I use new Varaint API's method `getGenerateBuildConfigProvider()` to retrieve `appPackageName`? I've tried to look for docs for the API and I've also checked the link from the warning, but, sadly, I haven't found any useful information.

Comment: `variant.getGenerateBuildConfigProvider().configure{ gbc ->
            println  "===" + gbc.appPackageName
        }` musisz pamiętać, że dostęp do tej zmiennej masz tylko w środku closure/action ... jak byś podał więcej szczegółów to pewnie lepsze rozwiązanie by się znalazło

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `variant.getGenerateBuildConfigProvider().get().appPackageName`
to get the package name

Answer (score -2):

I guess,this link will solve your problem.[API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412023/api-variant-getexternalnativebuildtasks-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-wi)

Kindly check for the dependencies,replace 'compile' or 'APi' to 'implementation',Use 'implementation' it will solve your warnings.

Comment: *I guess,this link will solve your problem* no, it will not ... if you would read the question from link you would know that it is prblem inside 3rd party plugin/script not it own