# How to fix gradle when this error appear?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I started a new project and put fire-base cloud:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.example.com.squawker"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

// RecyclerView
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

// Schematic dependencies for ContentProvider
apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
implementation 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic:0.6.3'

// Preferences Dependencies
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'

// Firebase dependency
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
}
// Apply the Google Services plugin. Make sure to add the google-services.json file in the app
// folder. You download it from the Firebase console
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this error apeared:

> WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
>   Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably because of [apt plugin which is already obsolete](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration). So, you need to remove the following:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

then change the following:

```
apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
```

with:

```
annotationProcessor 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
```

Comment: did it and the same problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52412023/7136932) Happy Coding!